# Passing local to partial rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, local, edit, partial

I dont know whats happenning. I just want to render an edit form via ajax, passing a local to a partial. my code is the following

Calling to edit action in my licencias_controller

```
<td><%= link_to '<i class="icon-pencil icon-black"></i>'.html_safe, edit_licencia_path(licencia), :remote => true %></td>
```

Here is my code in licencias_controller

```
      def edit
    @licencia = Licencia.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

And here is my code in edit.js.erb

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#modContLicencia').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'edit', :locals => {:licencia => @licencia})) %>');
    $('#modLicencia').modal('show');
});
```

So what i want is to show @licencia data in a _edit partial. First time i click to see its rendered ok, but if i click another @licencia object in index, the partial render the same @licencia object.So @licencia object is not being updated when i click another time to edit it. What im doing wrong?

Comment: Try with $('#modContLicencia').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'edit', :locals => {:licencia => @licencia})) %>");

Comment: though its not answer to your question `$('#modContLicencia')` must be unique

Comment: thanks for the answer, that was the problem!

Comment: +1 @BachanSmruty, didn't notice you're comment earlier.

Comment: @ vinodadhikary, It's ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of quotes are probably causing this problem for you.  Your `edit` would be treated an a variable in the `replaceWith` line.  You want to either escape the quotes wraping your `edit` partial using `\'` or use the following instead:

```
$('#modContLicencia').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'edit', :locals => {:licencia => @licencia})) %>");
```